# ng-repeat not populating <select> options

Tags: angularjs, json, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

My ng-repeat is not working. I'm trying to use it to traverse through this JSON object tags.tagNames. I know that the JSON object is in the scope and working, as I have it displayed above the `<select>` element (check the screenshot). Any ides on why it is not popuulating the `<select>` options?

![Screenshot][https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfAVG.png

**Javascript**

```
$http.get("getNames.php")
    .success(function (response) 
    {
            $scope.tags.tagNames = response.records;
    });

$scope.tags = 
    {
            repeatSelect: null,
            tagNames: null
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<label style = "margin-top :30px;" class="control-label">Search Note Tags: </label>
    <br>
    {{tags.tagNames}}

<select class="combobox form-control placeholder" class = "col-sm-6" ng-model = "tags.repeatSelect">
    <option value="">Tags</option>
    <option ng-repeat = "tag in tags.tagNames | orderBy: 'string'" value = "{{tag.string}}"> {{tag.string}} </option>

</select>
```

Comment: Your code is right and working correctly.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqStox4osZzp0e24kxXS?p=preview)

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: There is a better alternative to ng-repeat with option. Checkout [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select and see the below mentioned section.

> Using ngRepeat to generate select options

The is a plunker example which shows how to use `ng-repeat` to populate data in the select field.

There is an alternative which is `ng-options`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

> The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of
>   `<option>` elements for the `<select>` element using the array or object
>   obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression

It is illustrated by an example as well.

It is preferable to use `ngOptions` over `ngRepeat`

Also, can you provide the some more details about the problem. The error description or anything that can be used to figure out the solution.

Hope this helps :)